# How can I break `forall i: nat i < S k -> H` in Coq into `i < k and i=k`?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have to prove:

```
i < Datatypes.length (l0 ++ f :: nil) -> H
```

I have a separate hypothesis for `i < Datatypes.length l0` and `i = Datatypes.length l0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Require Import Arith.

SearchAbout lt le.
```

gives me (among other things):

```
le_lt_or_eq: forall n m : nat, n <= m -> n < m \/ n = m
```

Now. You have `i < S k` which is equivalent to `S i <= S k` and you want `i <= k`. So you need to peel-off `S` on each side.

```
SearchAbout le S.
```

gives me (among other things):

```
le_S_n: forall n m : nat, S n <= S m -> n <= m
```

By combining the two, you should be able to prove your goal:

```
Goal forall i k, i < S k -> i < k \/ i = k.
intros i k iltSk.
 apply le_lt_or_eq.
 apply le_S_n.
 assumption.
Qed.
```